# Play Framework strips "=" from URL during a Web Services call with empty values (Resulting in a 500 error at the end point)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Can you tell `Play Framework` to call an **exact URL** without messing around with the URL?

I want to do a GET Request with empty values.

However while inspecting the request done by Play, even though I have hand written an exact URL the Play Framework destroys my URL and make one up by itself.

An example would be something like:

- My handwritten request:   `http://address/?id=&filter=`
- Play frameworks request: `http://address/?id&filter`

I'm well familiar with that the equals sign is optional for empty values but this is of no interest when the endpoint exposing the rest API don't.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly relate to your problem, but I came across this [Google thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/124E4Fbbi8s) that explained how to call a method with multiple parameters...

> Other case:
>
> ```
> GET     /nice-test/:id/:name   controllers.Application.test(id:Long,
> name:String) will match /nice-test/10/james
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> GET     /ugly-test             controllers.Application.test(id:Long ?=
> 0, name:String ?= "") will match /ugly-test?id=10&name=james
> ```
>
> they both will be passed correctly to the same action, but ugly case
>   is just ... ugly:
>
> ```
> public static Result test(Long id, String name){
>     return ok("The "+name+" has id "+id);
> }
> ```
>
> What's more in your view you should build url for both cases in the
>   same way:
>
> ```
> <a href="@routes.Application.delete(user.id, user.name)">Show me user</a>
> ```

I'll write more here as I experiment with Play; I hope that sparked some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the empty strings as values should do the trick for you:

```
 http://address/?id=""&filter=""
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this approach doesn't work as the end point will give my an empty list with the empty string.